# "this" in my class inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm using [John Resig's class inheritance (for JavaScript) script](http://pastebin.com/kSKgXXq9). It allows you to define "classes" that you can inherit from. I've found one limitation: I cannot reference the class structure/base class (this) from within nested functions.

For example

```
var myclass = anotherclass.extend({ 
    dostuff: function() {
        $('#myelem').animate({ top: 100 }, function() { this.saystuff('Done'); });
    },

    saystuff: function(Message) {
        alert(Message);
    }
});

var foo = new myclass();
foo.dostuff();
```

When the script calls the callback which in turns calls `this.saystuff` it tries to call a method for the unnamed function I'm wrapping the callback in, so I can't call up the chain of functions.

The only way I've found to get around this it to call the variable that created the object, but that's not a good idea since that variable name should be able to change at any time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is out of scope.

```
dostuff: function() {
   var that=this;
    $('#myelem').animate({ top: 100 }, function() { that.saystuff('Done'); });
},
```

and looks like you are using jQuery which has proxy

```
dostuff: function() {
    $('#myelem').animate({ top: 100 }, $.proxy(this, this.saystuff, 'Done'); });
},
```

Comment: That would work, but do I have to do it for every function? There must be an automated way.

Comment: `$.proxy` looks useful, however I want to be try and be framework ambiguous. I think I'll go with your first suggestion.

Comment: @Jared Then use `bind` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @Jared You could also just refer to the object by name, i.e. `myclass.saystuff('Done');`. That remains consistent across functions, and doesn't require you to create a variable within each method to capture the context.

Comment: @Asad I don't want to hardcode the object variable name. That's not how OOP should work.

Comment: @Jared I'm not sure what you mean by "hardcoding" the variable name. If you want the handle for the class object to be locally independent of whatever name you use in the rest of your script, you can wrap it in an IIFE and pass the class object as the argument.

Answer (score 2):

The "base class" isn't inherently inaccessible. The problem is that the `this` keyword is simply repurposed within every new nested scope to refer to a different context. Within the callback you are passing to `animate`, `this` refers to the jQuery collection wrapping your element.

One way to get around this is to capture the context in a variable and enclose it in the callback:

```
dostuff: function() {
    var that = this;
    $('#myelem').animate({ top: 100 }, function() { that.saystuff('Done'); });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but you were 30 seconds too late. Plus epascarello added in the use of `$.proxy()`.